# Converting from lat/long to EPSG:2154 using ProjNet4GeoAPI?

Tags: c#, convert, latitude-longitude, epsg

I'm not experienced with GIS.
I received long/lat data and need to convert them to GIS.

Here are code examples from the library ProjNet4GeoAPI :
https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/blob/master/ProjNet.Tests/CoordinateTransformTests.cs

Here is the code I have after I started transforming the first example:

```
        public static void ToEpsg2154()
    {
        ICoordinateSystem epsg2154CoordinateSystem = (new CoordinateSystemFactory()).CreateFromWkt("PROJCS[\"RGF93 / Lambert-93\",GEOGCS[\"RGF93\",DATUM[\"Reseau_Geodesique_Francais_1993\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6171\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4171\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",49],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",44],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",46.5],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",3],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",700000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",6600000],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"2154\"],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH]]");
        IProjectedCoordinateSystem utm33 = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WGS84_UTM(33, true);
        ICoordinateTransformation trans = (new CoordinateTransformationFactory()).CreateFromCoordinateSystems(epsg2154CoordinateSystem, utm33);

        Coordinate[] points = new Coordinate[]
        {
            new Coordinate(290586.087, 6714000), new Coordinate(290586.392, 6713996.224),
            new Coordinate(290590.133, 6713973.772), new Coordinate(290594.111, 6713957.416),
            new Coordinate(290596.615, 6713943.567), new Coordinate(290596.701, 6713939.485)
        };

        Coordinate[] tpoints = trans.MathTransform.TransformList(points).ToArray();
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that I am missing something as the example inputs don't seem to be lat/long to me.

I am not sure what I should change or which other example I should start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed that point but I just realised that ProjNet4GeoAPI is based on Proj.NET, which helped me find more example.

The following one seems to have solved my problem: [Code to convert WGS84 coordinates to British National Grid Easting/Northings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/code-to-convert-wgs84-coordinates-to-british-national-grid-easting-northings)